# Typescript - "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided."

Tags: typescript

In a typescript project (using tsc 1.6.2, sublime 3 with the Typescript plugin 0.1.8) I have this typescript file:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/estree/estree.d.ts" />

export interface NodeWorker {

   nodeTypeFilters: Array<string>;

   enterNode(node: ESTree.Node, parent?: ESTree.Node): void;
   leaveNode(node: ESTree.Node, parent?: ESTree.Node): void;
}
```

I also have this tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "commonjs",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "listFiles": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "rootDir": "./src",
       "outDir": "../built/",
       "sourceMap": true,
   }
}
```

I have several other .ts files, which utilize imports and exports, but only on the file with the NodeWorker I get the error: "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided." on the export statement.

I cannot see the problem.

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet? VSCode also won't compile for my basic tutorial project, once I start adding modules. Typescript itself does compile to javascript. But I cannot find where to add this "--module" flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh man, this is too silly. The comma at

"sourceMap": true,

is wrong, of course.

Comment: Well, it did for me, you probably have a different issue then.

Comment: When using VS Code, the flag should be "out" instead of "outDir". This isn't documented anywhere it seems.